# expo implmenting the play/pause

Tags: react-native, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmb8y.jpg)

The problem occured when i was implementing the press pause and play like Instagram or tiktok app when playing the video in the React native expo. I followed the expo documentation but I feel it's a minor error.

Comment: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)